# How do you have a dynamic template name using class based generic views in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to emulate this with djangos new class based generic views and can't figure it out:

```
urlpatterns = pattern('', 
(r'^about/(\w+)/$', about_pages),
)

def about_pages(request, page):
  return direct_to_template(request, template="about/%s.html" % page)
```

Is this just not possible with class based views? Do you have to overwrite as_view()? If so how do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this (not tested):

`class AboutView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["about/%s.html" % self.args[0]]`